# Why does my localization only work on my Development-Machine?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, localization, uwp

I've localized my App in two languages (English and German) with the MulitlingualAppToolkit 4.0. English is the base language, while german is a translation based on the english one.
The translations are stored as resw-file inside folder "strings.en" and "strings.de".

In App.xaml.cs App() I set the culture like this:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = GetCurrentCulture();
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = GetCurrentCulture();

private CultureInfo GetCurrentCulture()
{
    var cultureName = new DateTimeFormatter("longdate", new[] {"US"}).ResolvedLanguage;
    return new CultureInfo(cultureName);
}
```

(I got this quiet weird way to the regional-culture in Windows 10 from this article https://www.pedrolamas.com/2015/11/02/cultureinfo-changes-in-uwp/ since I recognized that CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture are always "en-EN" no matter what i configurate in my machines regional- and language-settings)

To check if PrimaryLanguageOverride works as expected, I added a TextBox by the name of tbTest on my first Page and a button linkt to this event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = tbTest.Text;
    Frame.Navigate(this.GetType(), 0);
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "PrimaryLanguageOverride.txt"),
        DateTime.Now + " - Actual PrimaryLanguageOverride:\n    " + WIndows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { Helper.Log.LogUnhandledError(ex); }
}
```

Now comes the weird stuff:

When Debugging, or executing the App from my Development-Machine, everything works as expected, but when I make an appx-bundle and install it on another (Windows10-Desktop) device, the App does not recognize the its Language. 
In my situation, the device is set to german, regional as well as its language. Also when using the test-procedure, it defenetively gets the string I set , as long as it's a valid culture-name, e.g.: "en-EN", "en-US", "de-DE", "de", "en" (all of these are working fine on my development machine) if it's an invalid string, I get an exception, with a log-entry in my unhandled-error-log. It refresh the Page, and even writes the new-set language in my PrimaryLanguageOverride-Log, but it doesn't change any text I did translate.

So my question is, is this a common Issue (since I recognized in UWP/Win10 the culture-system is a little messed up) or do I use the wrong procedure to override the App-Culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with AppXBundling. When Installing bundles, it checks with the current OS for the installed Language packs and copies the relevant language resources from the bundle and omits the other language files. The objective of a single bundle is to copy necessary resources and build the application and therefore the languages which are not in the system are considered irrelevant. As a fix you could stop generating single bundles and create package for each CPU architecture. [Check this for more info](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d42c900-5591-45c9-b36d-1b5309cf3731/localization-does-not-work-properly-when-package-windows-81-c-xaml-app-by-setting-generate-app?forum=windowsstore)

Comment: Thx for the Answer. We allready found this solution, but since there are not that much ressources about MAT around, this will hopefully help other UWP developers.

Comment: Your welcome :D. So as the solution your using multiple packages for CPU architectures? Or manually loading resources from the application?

Comment: We are using an unbundled package at the moment, in deep hope for a recent fix, since microsoft presents MAT4.0 as their mean of choice for making an app multilingual.